# Is there a better way of getting an item from a MySQL db?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm fairly novice with SQL (reading right now). I'm wondering if there is a better way in PHP to get a MySQL data item than the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT `topic_id` from `topics` WHERE `user_id` = ".$userId." AND `topic` = ".$topic.";";
$topicRow = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($topicRow);
$topicId = $row['topic_id'];
```

I mean, 4 variables were created to get 1 item. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of vars is not a real issue, you could put the sql-string in your query if you want, but you're not really winning anything measurable. Please do not look for efficiency there. While the answers of @genesis and @patapizza are correct as far as I can see, they do not help you in any way to better your code, but only make it less readable.

You should look into parametereized queries (take a look at using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)): You should split your content (`$userId`) and your SQL-command.

An example from the manual:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

You don't have to escape the various things you put in your query, so you're save from injection.

(ow, and coincidently, only using 2 variables.. jeeeej :)  )

Comment: Thank you Nanne. I will definitely look into PDO

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have not SQL-escaped `$userId` and `$topic` your code is susceptible to SQL-injection. I would also use the PDO API instead which is database management system independent.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a database abstraction layer, like [ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/).

The thing is, you do not want to constantly get involved into escaping variables, and query concatenation is something which shouldn't be done in many places in the code. Having all that, the best thing you can do, is Really, using something like ADOdb, or make something of your own, in case ADOdb doesn't respond to your needs.

It is absolutely incorrect, from an architect's point of view, to mix logic, real program logic, with stuff like technical means of getting at your data (open connection, define command, get result, read result, etc). In that logic you just have to Get your data. You don't need to see a database connection in your logic.